# Ударение в слове "исчерпать"

Tags: орфоэпия

Давно уже узнал, что правильным в этом слове считается ударение на Е, *исч**е**рпать.* Но реально я ***никогда*** не слышал, чтобы так говорили в смысле ***истратить, израсходовать что-то.***

Почему же возникло такое несоответствие норм тому, как на самом деле говорят, и какому же ударению всё-таки стоит следовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...и какому же ударению всё-таки стоит следовать?

Следуйте тому произношению, к которому привыкли.

Словарь Ушакова допускал ударение в слове *исчерпать* и на втором, и на третьем слоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Со времён же Ожегова до недавнего времени правильным словарями признавалось ударение только на втором слоге.

Вы пишете:

> Но реально я никогда не слышал, чтобы так говорили...

Я слышал. Но значительно чаще слышал *исчерпать* с ударением на третьем слоге.

Что в словарях сейчас? В наиболее авторитетных, на мой взляд, словарях отражены  в качестве допустимых оба варианта ударения. Это есть в ***РОС (4-ое изд., 2012):***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть и в **"Большом орфоэпическом словаре русского языка" (авторы: Каленчук М.Л., Касаткин Л.Л., Касаткина Р.Ф.; М., 2012)**, причём в этом словаре вариант с ударением на втором слоге снабжён пометой "допуст.", в качестве же основного уже приводится вариант с ударением на третьем слоге: *исчерпАть.* См.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У моей сестры несколько лет назад было (вроде ещё в школе даже) что-то типа теста с ударениями, и вроде там правильным считалось ударение на Е в этом слове. С тех пор я был в недоумении всё время. Спасибо, что разрешили их, указав на словари, в которых приветствуется или признаётся единственно правильным ударение на А! И то, что Вы слышали, как говорят на Е, в любом случае интересное наблюдение.

Comment: Слава, не знаю, слышали ли Вы, что существует список официаьных словарей, грамматик. Так вот, Каленчук в этот список не входит. Для работников ТВ, радио, журналистов, и т.п. все же остается правильным вариант на втором слоге.

Comment: Правда, об этом на Грамоте.ру есть статья, в котором автор (Бельчиков, если не ошибаюсь) доктор филологических наук недоумевал, на основании каких критериев исходили. Тем не менее вот официально утвержденный список.

Comment: Список грамматик, словарей и справочников, содержащих нормы современного русского литературного языка при его использовании в качестве государственного языка Российской Федерации

1. Орфографический словарь русского языка. Букчина Б.З., Сазонова И.К., Чельцова Л.К. - М.: "АСТ-ПРЕСС", 2008. - 1288 с.

2. Грамматический словарь русского языка: Словоизменение. Зализняк А.А. - М.: "АСТ-ПРЕСС", 2008. - 794 с.

3. Словарь ударений русского языка. Резниченко И.Л.- М.: "АСТ-ПРЕСС", 2008. - 943 с.

Comment: 4. Большой фразеологический словарь русского языка. Значение. Употребление. Культурологический комментарий. Телия В.Н. - М. : "АСТ-ПРЕСС", 2008. - 782 с.

Comment: Слава, а РОС (4-ое изд., 2012), это не тот же самый словарь, что на Грамоте?

Comment: кстати, Слава, раз уж зашел разговор. Не могли бы Вы посмотреть, какое ударение в слове апостроф в словаре Каленчук.

Comment: _Серж: Не могли бы Вы посмотреть..._ === Посмотрел: _апострОф (! не рек. апОстроф)_. === СерЖ: _"а РОС (4-ое изд., 2012), это не тот же самый словарь, что на Грамоте?"_  На Грамоте тоже РОС, только предыдущая версия, пока не полностью откорректированная.

Comment: А вот меня удивляет апострОф, всегда, до недавнего времени,говорил апОстроф. Мне как-то непрывычно первый вариант. Они допустили столько вариантов, а этот нет.

Comment: Да, странно, по-английски ударение в апострофе тоже падает на 2-й слог.

Answer (score 2):

Сегодня нормативным является ударение на втором слоге. Хотя, по мнению Грамоты.ру, в словарях есть и ударение на третьем слоге (но предпочтение отдается ударению на втором слоге).

P.S. Не совсем понятно, из каких критериев Вы исходите при определении норм. В русском языке очень много слов ударение которых на практике путают. Вот некоторые из них: вкл**ю**чит (разг.) и включ**и**т (лит. норм.). Балов**а**ть (лит. норм.) и б**а**ловать (разг.). Вспомните классический пример: зв**о**н**и**т. 
Связано это с тем, что ударение в русском языке разноместное и подвижное.

Comment: _Серж: Сегодня нормативным является ударение на втором слоге. Хотя, по мнению Грамоты.ру, в словарях есть и ударение на третьем слоге ( но предпочтение отдается ударению на втором слоге)_. === Серж, Вы не правы. Сами же пишете, что в словарях присутствует ударение на третьем слоге.  Почему же тогда такое ударение Вы считаете ненормативным? Что Вы понимаете под нормативностью? И по поводу вот этого: _"предпочтение отдаётся.."_  Вопрос: кем отдаётся? Вами? Автором ответа на Грамоте? Людьми на улице? Явно ведь, что не словаристами, зафиксировавшими именно такое ударение в своих словарях.

Comment: ВклЮчит, звонИт грамотные люди говорят именно так. А чтобы говорили исчЕрпать, никогда не слышал! Также я часто слышу *м**а**стерски* от многих интеллигентных людей, что тоже расстраивает. :(

Comment: Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка. Литературное произношение и ударение начала ХХI века: нормы и её варианты.
(Каленчук М. Л., Касаткин Л. Л., Касаткина Р. Ф.  – М., 2012).ДРДР, признают два варианта.  Русский орфографический словарь: около 180 000 слов / Российская академия наук. Институт русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова / О.Е. Иванова, В.В. Лопатин (отв. ред.), И.В. Нечаева, Л.К. Чельцова. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — Москва, 2004. — 960 с. тоже признают два варианта. У Ушакова только исчерп***а***ть( если верить интернет-изданию)., у Ожегова только исч***е***рпать.

Comment: _Серж: Слава, удивительно, что говорите это Вы. Вариант **и**счерпать не отвечает строгой литературной норме..._ === Тьфу ты... Да разве я где-нибудь когда-нибудь говорил о ударении на первом слоге? По-моему, и ни в одном словаре о таком ударении ничего не говорится... Или я не прав?

Comment: Нее, я хотел написать: исчерп***а***ть. Сейчас удалю и заново напишу.

Comment: Слава, удивительно, что говорите это Вы. Вариант исчерп***а***ть не отвечает строгой литературной норме, и большинство словарей его не признают. Вопрос, кем отдается - задайте авторам словарей. Что касается меня, я могу говорить и с ударением на третьем слоге ( в повседневной речи)

Comment: Вопрос в том, Серж, можете Вы говорить с ударением **на втором слоге** или нет! Естественно это для Вас?

Comment: Я привык, сейчас механически могу говорить и так и так.